# Script using GPU throws error when running app on Shiny server

Tags: r, shiny, gpu

I have written some code in R using the Shiny package. The app runs alright when running `shiny::runApp()` from RStudio.

I've tried to host the app on a Shiny server and the GUI starts up correctly. However, a plot should appear on the right when the button "Enviar informacion" is clicked. (You can see how the app looks [here](https://iibm.shinyapps.io/spike_sorting/), but it won't work though because that link is not on Shiny server but on Shinyapps.io).

The relevant part of the logfile is the following:

```
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:38327
Loading required package: Rcpp
Warning: Error in [: subscript out of bounds
  211: FUN [/srv/shiny-server/spike_sorting/server.R#82]
  210: apply
  209: cluster_som_h [/srv/shiny-server/spike_sorting/server.R#82]
  ...
```

So the error is inside the function `cluster_som_h`. After trying some stuff, I found out what is causing the error, but don't know how to fix it. Inside this function, I make use of the function `Rsomoclu.train()` from the [package Rsomoclu](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rsomoclu/Rsomoclu.pdf), with `kernelType = 1`. This means that the function is run on the GPU. If I set `kernelType = 0`, then the app works okay with both `runApp()` and from the Shiny server. **So that's where the problem is: for some reason, running the function on the GPU is not working if the app is run from the Shiny server, but it does work if it is run from RStudio using `runApp()`.**

Maybe there is something going on because I have CUDA installed on my computer but when I try to run it from the server something happens. Is there a way to fix this? I believe running the code from this specific computer no matter where on the LAN the app is run would solve this. Is this possible?

Comment: My guess is `algorithm_output <<- cluster_som_h(size, epochs, path)`. Put that in its own `reactive` object instead of using the super-assignment operator.

Comment: @Phil Would it make sense for it to work when doing `runApp()` if that was the problem? What I mean is: if that is the issue, wouldn't the `runApp()` method fail too?

Comment: Difficult for me to answer without fully testing, but It could work due to a difference in environment between your local machine and the server. I'd suggest changing `algorithm_output` to become a reactive object, and see if it solves the issue. Just remember to add `()` throughout when calling `algorithm_output`.

Comment: @Phil I've tried writing some simple code inside `cluster_som_h` instead of the actual code, and the error has disappeared. Therefore, there must be something wrong with that specific function. I still don't understand why the `runApp()` approach works and the server doesn't, though. I'll try some more things tomorrow and update the question.

Comment: Based on your error message, the error comes from the cluster_som_h function, so it is definitly relevant.

Comment: @Phil I've found the error. I've updated the question with relevant info.

Comment: @SeGa I didn't know how to interpret the logfile (sorry for that, I feel so noob right now). I've found what was happening, I've updated the question.

Comment: I'm unfortunately not able to help you. However, if you're using shinyapps.io I think the people from RStudio could help you. https://community.rstudio.com/c/shiny

Comment: @Tendero. Don't worry, they look indeed very messy ;) Which Shiny server are you using or do you have acces to the server admin? And is it necessary to run on the GPU?

Comment: @SeGa I've been able to solve it! I've posted the solution. Sorry for wasting your time, and thanks for your help!

Comment: Great, I'm glad you figured it out! +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some (basic) research, I found out what was happening. I have CUDA installed only in my user in Ubuntu, so I had to change the first line of the file `/etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf` so that the user was the right one:

```
# Instruct Shiny Server to run applications as the user "my_name"
run_as my_name;
```